# CSS: paragraph display inline when it shouldn't

Tags: css

I'm trying to design a Card but my `<p>` text is somehow inline. I don't want that. I tried `display: block;`and other options but that doesn`t work.

I work with Bootstrap and CSS but as far as I know, this is a plain CSS question.

Here is my Html for one card:

```
<div class="">
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top" src="../../../assets/images/offer_1.jpg">
<div class="card-body text-center">

  <h1>{{offer.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{offer.description}}</p>
  <h2>{{offer.price}}€</h2>
</div>
```

And here my SCSS:

```
$font-serif: 'Playfair Display', serif;
$font-sans-serif: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

$color_price: #F96D00;
$color_description: #b8b8b8;

.card {
    border-radius: 0;

    .card-body {
        padding: 3rem;

        h1 {
            font-family: $font-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.45;
            font-size: 26px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: $font-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.45;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: $color_price;
        }

        p {
            font-family: $font-serif;
            line-height: 1.45;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: $color_description;
            height: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Edit: The Problem is the paragraph has a flixible width but the text inside is somehow always inline and wider then the paragraph itself.

Comment: it not inline, it's a perfect block

Comment: How do you expect a block element to look?

Comment: I guess the `overflow: hide` made the actual problem hard to see. I have updated the code and image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use overflow:hidden or !important on text-align: center.

You need to set a maximum width on the card element that is the parent of the P.
Look at your styles rendered in a codepen:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/vaaMoO

The name and price are left-aligned, and the description is center aligned.

This is because you've used a helper class 'text-center' I assume this comes from some framework that you have not mentioned in your question. The helper class will not cascade down if you have alignment set on the h1 or h2 element, in that case you need to apply it to the actual element:

HTML:

```
<div class="">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../../../assets/images/offer_1.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="text-center">{{offer.name}}</h1>
        <p class="text-center">{{offer.description}}</p>
        <h2 class="text-center">{{offer.price}}€</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
$font-serif: 'Playfair Display', serif;
$font-sans-serif: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

$color_price: #F96D00;
$color_description: #b8b8b8;

.card {
    border-radius: 0;
    //Added width & background color for demo
    width: 320px;
    background: azure;
 .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
.card-body {
    padding: 3rem;
    display: block;

h1 {
    font-family: $font-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.45;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: $font-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.45;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: $color_price;
}

p {
    font-family: $font-serif;
    line-height: 1.45;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: $color_description;
    height: 100px;

}
}
}
```

Here's a working pen with the styles above:
https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/gjjJpw

Comment: _"The helper class will not cascade down"_ - `text-align: center` absolutely _will_ cascade down. It is an inherited property. http://jsfiddle.net/bwr5k3uq/ . There is no need to apply it to every element.

Comment: Fair point Turnip. I didn't mean that, but I realise what I wrote wasn't clear, I was trying to address the !bangImportant OP added on the paragraph tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The `text-center` is a bootstrap class as far as I know and for me every element is centered so I don't really see the problem here (it doesn't work with and without it). I have also removed the `text-align: center` because I don't need it anyways. Thats not the problem. Also I can't set the cards to a certain width because I need it to be flexible. I have updated the code and the image so it describes the problem a little better.